# Deleting the objects from Django table is not working

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views

On a button click i want to delete an object from django database table. when i press delete button the desired object is gone. But when i refresh the page, the data is again loaded. How can i solve that error. I want to delete that object forever.

Here is my code:

models.py

```js
class activities(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField(max_length=60)
    description=models.TextField()
    date=models.TextField(max_length=60)
    list=models.TextField(max_length=60)
    Dates=models.DateField(max_length=60)
    root=models.ForeignKey(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```js
def dashboards(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        user_id=request.POST.get('var')
        a = activities.objects.filter( id=user_id)
        a.delete()
      
        try:
            response = dashboard(request)
        except:
            return render(request,'contact.html')
```

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe **user_id** matching data is not present in the database. Please confirm.

Comment: Of course. It was the error. Thank you for your answer.